# How to discard debug messages using rsyslog?

Tags: linux, rsyslog

We have a requirement to write incoming debug messages to our rsyslog server, but not forward them on to our Splunk server. I have tried putting *.debug stop in front of our local rules, but that is not working.  Any ideas how to prevent .debug messages from being forwarded.

Comment: Also I had some fight with rsyslog. Finally I've found that the switch from syslog-ng to rsyslog was a bad decision, I am sorry to say but imho the rsyslog is far from the quality/configurability what we would expect from such an important software. syslog-ng is a well-going and well-configurable log daemon, it is still developed/maintained and works well. There `flags(final);` would be the key in the `log` entities.

Comment: Can you show us your configuration file? The order of the log message processing is based on the order of directives in the configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you work with include config files. This makes order of processing very important. Details are in the [rsyslog include documentation](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/rainerscript/include.html).

Based on this assumption I guess that you do the `*.debug stop` at a place **after** the messages has already been forwarded.

Alternatively, you may use a very old version which does not understand `stop`. In this case, you can do `*.debug ~`, which is the very-old style equivalent.